# How to display reset password link on gerrit portal?

Tags: gerrit

I am using LDAP mode of authentication and have written web service and clients to enable gerrit users to reset their passwords should they happen to forget it. For that, I added the following line into gerrit.config file:
[auth]
  httpPasswordUrl = http://domain.com:port/Register/ChangePassword

However, this link is not visible anywhere on gerrit, either before login or post login. Can someone guide me on how to make this link "visible" to one and all (users)?

Answer (score 1):

This link is displayed in the Settings -> HTTP Password screen. So this link cannot be used for users who forgot their password. I don't think there is an option to display such a link for non-logged-in users.

A possible solution would be displaying a custom footer / header which adds this link: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-themes.html#_html_header_footer

Comment: The HTTP Password screen sets/resets HTTP passwords for gerrit users iff the mode of communication/authentication through CLI is HTTP (and not ssh). However, the header-footer thing is an alternative to it, for sure. Thanks.